# Как исправить условие в сессии php?

Tags: php, сессия

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['name']) == ' ') {
 
  header("Location: https://www.google.com/");
   
}
?>
```

Сессия name пустая, а переадрессация не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать перенаправление на страницу google

Comment: убери echo 1;  ))

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['name']) == ' '` как и зачем вы сравниваете boolean со строкой? В чём смысл? Используйте empty()